# Replacing all type of BBCODE image links into HTML image links

Tags: php, regex

I have this script for replacing BBCODE image tags to HTML tags

```
$text = "[img]https://somelink/2/3/pic.jpg[/img]
[img]https://somelink/2/3/pic.jpg[/img]
[img]https://somelink/2/3/pic.jpg[/img]";

echo preg_replace(
'~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp))\[/img\]~s',
'<img src="$1" alt="" />',
$text);
```

This forks for links, which ends up whit some of given extensions: `.jpg` `.jpeg` ...

But if link are like: `[img]https://somelink/2/3/pic.jpg`**?w=bla**`[/img]`

Then this regex pattern fails.

What would be appropriate pattern for all type of image links? I tried:

`~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp).*)\[/img\]~Us`

But this also not works

Comment: what will be desired src in the case which is failing you want to `?w=bla` to be added to src ?

Comment: If you want to match all that can follow, you could make the `.*` non greedy to `.*?` to prevent over matching and make the e optional to omit 1 alternation `\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp).*?)\[/img\]` See https://regex101.com/r/nQFOGz/1

Comment: is this what you're looking for [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK2CgW/1/)

Comment: @CodeManiac - Yes, all get parameters added to `src`

Comment: You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/kK2CgW/2/)

Comment: Thank you guys, all of your solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible that the query string parameters can also contain `[` or `]` you could match the question mark `\?` followed by matching until you encounter `[/img]` and make use of a possessive quantifier to prevent unnecessary backtracking

**Explanation**

```
\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)(?:\?(?:[^[]++|\[(?!/img\]))*+)?)\[/img]
```

- `\[img\]` Match `[img]`
- `(` Capturing group

  - `https?://.*?` Match http with optional s, `://` and 0+ times any char non greedy
  - `\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp)` Match a dot and any of the listed options
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `\?` Match ?
    - `(?:[^[]++|\[(?!/img\]))*+` Repeat 0+ times matching not `[` or match `[` when what is directly on the right is not `/img]`
  - `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `)` Close capturing group
- `\[/img]` Match `[/img]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PCOjBk/1)

Comment: Thank you very much for edge case solution and great explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp).*?)\[/img\]
```

- `\[img\]` - Matches `[img]`
- `(https?://.*?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp).*?)` - Matches URL containing any of above extensions
- `\[/img\]` - Matches `[/img]`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kK2CgW/4/)

You can visualize [regex here](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24)

Note:-  as you're using `U` flag you can safely remove `?` after quantifiers, i.e

```
\[img\](https?://.*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp).*)\[/img\]
```

Comment: Not downwoter btw, but this solution not works. as @Thefourthbird said, `you could make the .* non greedy to .*?`

Comment: @OTAR  `~\[img\](https?://.*?\.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp).*)\[/img\]~Us` you already have selected `U` flag which means ungreddy ( makes quantifier lazy) isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, just I have `https?://.*?` . So in this case should remove last question mark from here

Comment: `~\[img\](https?://.*\.(?:jpe?g|gif|png|bmp).*)\[/img\]~Us` this will work

Comment: @OTAR yes you can safely remove `?` after any quantifier if you use `U` flag